# How do I prove both arcs are equal?

Tags: triangles, circles, angle, arc-length

As in the following image, the segments AD, DB, BE and EC make the same angle (x) relative to the diameter of the circle QP. How can I prove the arcs L1 (AB) and L2 (BC) are equal?

[image]

Comment: Do we have the point $E$ as a center of the circle?

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak it shouldn't matter, so you can assume it is

Comment: This exact same question was asked and closed previously for the reason that there was no work shown.

Comment: E is not necessarily in the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is trivially answered by simply extending $AD$ and $CE$ and observing their intersection will meet at the circle at a point $B'$, for the reason that we can simply reflect $A, B, C$ across diameter $QP$ to $A', B', C'$ and the given angles force $D$ to be collinear with $AB'$ and $E$ collinear with $CB'$.  Thus $\angle AB'C$ is an inscribed angle, and $\triangle DB'E$ is is isosceles; therefore, $\angle AB'B = \angle BB'C$ and by the inscribed angle theorem, the subtended arcs $L_1$ and $L_2$ are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Just an illustration of @heropup's answer.

[image]